# Select all checkboxes under tbody not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, html-table

I'm not sure why this jquery is not working. What I want is pretty straightforward: selecting all check boxes under the region. Could someone help tell why it's not working?

```js
$(function(){
  $('.select_all').change(function() {
    var checkthis = $(this);
    var checkboxes = $(this).next('tbody').find('.region_ct');
    if(checkthis.is(':checked')) {
      checkboxes.attr('checked', true);
    } else {
      checkboxes.attr('checked', false);  }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Americas</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><input type="checkbox" name="region_am_all" class="select_all" value="X" /> Select All</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="region_ct" value="X"  /> Argentina</td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="region_ct" value="X"  /> Barbados</td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Asia</th>
  </tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: `tbody` isn't next sibling nor sibling anyway of `.select_all` checkbox

Comment: oh, if so, how to find the next tbody, right after select_all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues there:

1. I would **strongly** recommend against intermixing `tr` and `tbody` elements. If you're going to use `tbody` (and you should), use it consistently. Browsers may relocate `tr` elements into generated `tbody` elements.
2. The element you're calling `next` on doesn't have a following sibling (at all, much less the one you're looking for). You have to traverse up the hierarchy to the `tr` (if you don't fix #1) or the `tbody` (if you do).
3. You don't use `attr` to set `checked`, you use `prop`; and you can use your existing `checked` boolean rather than `if/else`, giving is simply `checkboxes.prop("checked", this.checked);`

Example with updated `tbody`s, and I've added some countries in the Asia area to demonstrate that only the relevant checkboxes are checked:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.select_all').change(function() {
    var checkthis = $(this);
    var checkboxes = $(this).closest('tbody').next().find('.region_ct');
    checkboxes.prop("checked", this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=2>Americas</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>
        <input type="checkbox" name="region_am_all" class="select_all" value="X" />Select All</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="region_ct" value="X" />Argentina</td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="region_ct" value="X" />Barbados</td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th colspan=2>Asia</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2>
        <input type="checkbox" name="region_am_all" class="select_all" value="X" />Select All</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="region_ct" value="X" />China</td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="region_ct" value="X" />Vietnam</td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You might also consider putting the `select_all` inside the same `tbody` with the checkboxes, so you could do away with `next`.

Comment: thanks for fixing the codes and explaining! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`tbody` isn't sibing of `.select_all`. You need to use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select parent of `.select_all` and use `.find()` to select `.region_ct` in it. Also you don't need to use `if/else` to `check/uncheck` checkbox. Only set `this.checked` to checked attribute of checkbox using `.prop()`.

```js
$('.select_all').change(function() {
    $(this).closest('table').find('.region_ct').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Americas</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><input type="checkbox" name="region_am_all" class="select_all" value="X" /> Select All</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="region_ct" value="X"  /> Argentina</td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="region_ct" value="X"  /> Barbados</td>
      <td class="center"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>Asia</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think the goal with the `next` thing is that there will be other, unrelated `.region_ct` boxes in other `tbody`s.